# Access combobox issue?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access I try to search using a combobox. I have 2 combo boxes, one of them works normally but another have an issue with.

The failing code is as follows:

```
Private Sub ComName_Click()

    Dim EmName As String
    EmName = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Order WHERE  AssignedTo = '" & Me.ComName & "'"
    Me.SearchForm.Form.RecordSource = EmName
    Me.SearchForm.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

and face run-time error 3464 "data type mismatch in criteria expression":

[image: run-time error, data type mismatch in criteria expression]

[image]

Comment: Assigning recordsource will requery your form. You don't need to perform additional requery.

Comment: ComName is bound to EmpId?  use `AfterUpdate`event not `Click`.

Comment: What is the structure of `tbl_Order`?

Answer (score 1):

*EmpID* is most likely numeric, thus:

```
EmName = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Order WHERE  AssignedTo = " & Me.ComName & ""
```

Comment: I tested that but i still face the same error any help plzz as i need to to filter using combobox

Comment: It might be simpler and faster to set the _Filter_ property of the form, not the RecordSource.